# install ubuntu touch on a Hisense Sero 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

I want to install ubuntu touch  on a Hisense Sero 7.
So far, I have not been able to root the device. I have tried tutorials online, none have worked. I tired rooting with SuperOneClick2013 v2.3.3, to no avail. Can someone recommend a tool to root this device? Has anyone installed Ubuntu on this device yet?

I am not interested in running a VNC virtual machine with Ubuntu within the Android OS.

Comment: To root your device take a look at http://www.sero7.com or XDA developers website.

Comment: I tired it, but the drivers just dont work. I have spent several hours tracing out DCOM errors, alternate drivers, service packs, and it still doesnt work. A linux tool for rooting Android devices?